# Is the Docusign API object library exposed?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working with existing Word documents that are currently updated in a mail merge.  I would like to be able to (on the high-level) just be able to convert these documents in run-time to a Docusign template with signable fields and automatically send them (without having to upload documents to the Docusign site, etc., etc;).  I don't want to change our current workflow, just add a "behind-the-scenes" step that automatically creates and sends the DocuSign envelope(s) to the specified signer.  The users won't be signing into Word or DocuSign, they'll be literally clicking a "Generate and Send Document" button.  Is the Docusign API object exposed in a way that makes this possible?

Chris Fleetwood
Software Developer
N.C. Partnership for Children, Inc.
cfleetwood@smartstart.org

Comment: Hey Chris. Couple clarifying questions: Do you already have a DocuSign template build via the DocuSign app UI? Do you expect the format and field location(s) of your document to change, or rather just the recipients?

Comment: @MatthewRoknich  Hey Matthew.  I do not.  I am in the very early stages of looking at the DocuSign functionality and determining how to implement it in my current environment.  i do not have any DocuSign template built.  I guess one of the underlying questions I have involves whether or not a template has to be built by default.  What I was envisioning that I could auto-convert a current Word document into a DocuSign template via code and just be ablle to insert the signable fields and then construct and send the envelope object.

Comment: I realize that this is a rather simplistic way of looking at it.  But Word documents are used extensively by our users, and they are the type of users who...well, let's just say that IT will be responsible for the technical aspect of DocuSign, so I would like to make that as automated as possible, requiring minimal IT intervention on a regular basis.

Comment: Check out the solution by inbar below. If you need/want further customization beyond our many pre-built integrations, then we can talk eSignature API :)

Comment: @MatthewRoknich  The Word document is currently updated in a Word mail merge.  That merged document will be the one sent to recipients.  The current plan is for that process to remain unchanged.  The merged document would potentially be sent via Docusign.  The recipients would be, as far as Docusign is concerned, the only thing to change.

Comment: @MatthewRoknich  I took a look at the suggested solutions.  The Word DocuSign Add-In would work, except I would like to be able to automatically "do" whatever the add-in supports without actually having to initiate it from Word.

Comment: @MatthewRoknich  Our existing process has automated the Word mail merge process; the result is an merged Word document.  I want to take that created .doc file, convert it to a DocuSign template, automatically add the signature fields, and send it (in Outlook) to the intended signees/recipients, automatically (during runtime) from our corporate application (which is written in VB.NET).

Comment: @MatthewRoknich So, my question is:  Is the DocuSign API exposed in such a way that it can be referenced, say, within a .NET application, to convert a Word doc in run-time to a DocuSign template with signable fields and automatically send them (without having to upload documents to the DocSsign site, etc., etc;)?

Comment: Yes. the create Envelope method of the eSignature API allows you to define an envelope, which contains a document(s), recipients, and fields. If you set the status of that envelope to "sent" it will immediately send for signature. Now... I doubt that you will want to do this repeatedly because you have to place and assign the fields on every request. We have a feature in beta at the moment called "auto-tagging" which sounds more like what you're asking for - Specify a document(s) via API and the doc is tagged automatically.

Comment: @MatthewRoknich That's good to hear.  It gives me a starting point.  Since we are literally just starting out with Docusign development, what is the timeline for the "auto-tagging" feature to be available for testing?  Is there documentation available for that feature on the DocuSign site?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do that is using the [DocuSign Connector for Flow and PowerApps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/docusign/)

This does require you to have an account with Microsoft and potentially pay them extra (I'm not sure about that part, you would have to check with them) but it seems to have the functionality you need, without having to write any code.

[DocuSign also has a Word Add](https://www.docusign.com/solutions/microsoft/word)-In that does support templates, but only through the template-match feature. If the document you are authoring looks like a document stored in your DocuSign account inside a template - you can use this template form Word with one-click.